# Django form saving in database and send email with formspree.io

Tags: django, email, django-forms

I'm looking for set up a ticket service for my company and I am getting a little problem between my Django form and [Formspree.io](https://formspree.io).

Users create a ticket with my Django form. Then, their tickets are storaged in my database and my application send an email to support@mycompany.fr with `Formspree`.

When I click on `submit button`, the mail is well send to my email address but data are not saved in my database. Up to now I don't find a way to do this process ...

My models looks like :

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    Etat = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices = CHOIX_ETAT_TICKET, verbose_name="Etat du ticket")
    Nom = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Nom du createur")
    Prenom = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Prenom du createur")
    Telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Téléphone')
    Mail = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Email')
    Objet = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Objet du ticket')
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Description du ticket')
    Creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Utilisateur = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Utilisateur")
```

My form looks like this :

```
class TicketFormulaire(forms.ModelForm):

    Utilisateur = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    Etat = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta :
        model = Ticket
        fields = ["Etat", "Nom", "Prenom", "Telephone", "Mail", "Objet", "Description", "Utilisateur"]
```

My view looks like this :

```
@login_required
def Identity_Ticket(request) :

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = TicketFormulaire(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
            post = form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Le formulaire a été enregistré !')
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Home'))

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Le formulaire est invalide !")

    else:
        form = TicketFormulaire()

        form.fields['Utilisateur'].initial = request.user.last_name + " " + request.user.first_name
        form.fields['Etat'].initial = 'En attente'
    return render(request, 'Identity_Societe_Ticket.html', {"form" : form, })
```

And finally my html template :

```
<h4 class="subtitle"><b> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span> Création d'un nouveau ticket</b></h4>

    <form autocomplete="off" class = "form" method='POST' action='https://formspree.io/support@mycompany.fr'> {% csrf_token %} <br></br>
        {{ form.as_p}} 
        <br></br>

        <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer le ticket" onclick="return confirm('Valider le formulaire ?')" /> 
    </form>
```

Do you have a solution in order to save data in my database in first time, then send the email ?

Any help could be appreciate ;)

**______________
UPDATE : 
______________**

My HTML file looks like :

```
<h4 class="subtitle"><b> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span> New ticket</b></h4>

    <form autocomplete="off" class = "form" method='POST' action='' enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %} <br></br>    
        {{ form.as_p}} 
        <br></br>

        <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Confirm the ticket ?')" /> 
    </form>

    <script>
        var $TicketForm = $('#someid');
        $TicketForm.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '//formspree.io/support@mycompany.fr',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $TicketForm.append('<div class="alert alert--loading">Envoi du ticket en cours</div>');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $TicketForm.find('.alert--loading').hide();
                    $TicketForm.append('<div class="alert alert--success">Le ticket a été envoyé ! </div>');
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    $TicketForm.find('.alert--loading').hide();
                    $TicketForm.append('<div class="alert alert--error">Il semble y avoir une erreur</div>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

If I don't add `id="someid"` in `<form>`, data are saved in my DB and email is not send, but if I write `id="someid"`, email is send but none data is saved in my database ... The issue is there ...

Answer (score 2):

Well you have given the `action='https://formspree.io/support@mycompany.fr'` 
parameter in form, so that your form is submitting to formspree.io site. Rather than doing that submit your form with your app function URL and do the formspree.io processing in django views after the form is saved.

**Edit:**
I do not know about the formspee.io but i understood your query,
one way you can do it  by using ajax,

change to

```
<button type="button" id="someid">
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" />

$("#someid").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "//formspree.io/youremail@gmail.com", 
        method: "POST",
        data: {message: "hello!","extradatagoeshere":""},
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data)
        {
          // now submit your actual form to db by form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Or use python request library to post data after the **view function** logic of form save ,

```
import requests
url = 'https://formspree.io/support@mycompany.fr'

data = {"yourdata":"data"} # pass a whole bunch of dict which needed to be send in data

requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: You're right, but I'm searching How I can write that ;)

Comment: See the edited answer.This can help you for your query

Comment: I'm trying to use your Ajax answer. If `type=button`, the form ticket is not saved in my database but I receive the email.
Then, I don't really understand your comment in the ajax part :/

Comment: after submitting the form you receiving the token from formspree?

Comment: after submitting the form, I reveive the email, but data are not saved in my database, no redirections, etc .. I don't modify my view, just change `<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer le ticket" onclick="return confirm('Valider le formulaire ?')" />` by `<button type="button" id="someid"> Enregistrer le ticket</button> `

Comment: ok then in your success of ajax see output by typing console.log(data). And in the success of ajax have you written $(form).submit() ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149594/discussion-between-deadpool-and-aniket).

Answer (score 1):

your action is posting the data to `formspree` website and not to the view of your site, so you can never get the data and save it to database.

if you really want to do this, one way is use `ajax` to post the data to your `django view` on click of submit button,  you can put an `id` in the `button` and check `onclick` an `ajax` will be called.

and the form will stay as it is.

hope this helps you

Comment: I have never used Ajax so it's a big hole for myself :/ There's possibility to add different django form actions maybe ?

Comment: ajax is very easy, just search how to post data using ajax om button click with id, you will get a hell lot of examples, or try to find ajax in django template

Comment: and with different django actions you need 2 forms, that is not a good idea i guess, as user wont fill the form twice

Comment: Yes you're right. I will look in details ajax, but `formspree` seems to be really easy to use ^^

Comment: yeah maybe, but for mailing you can use django mails, after saving the data in the database you can simply send a mail with the data to your support mail